Is it bad to repeat the same word in a sentence?
I keep finding myself using the same words repeatedly whenever I write or talk to people, so I'm wondering if this is a bad habit to have.
For example,

Volunteering makes me feel good because I love doing good things for my community.

Notice that I used the word 'good' twice in this sentence. I just want to know if I should avoid using the same word twice to make my sentences better. Thanks.

Compare How to avoid needless repetition, On repeating adjectives, repetition of can and other questions. It's often considered poor style but can be justified; in your case, there should be no trouble finding alternative synonyms for good.

They're very different senses; one is feeling well contented; one is virtuous /
principled / beneficial. While this can be good (catchy) in some cases, and bad in others (confusing or sounding silly), I'd say it's hardly noticeable here.

But if you want to get rid of the repetition, try using "happy" or "satisfied" for the first one, or "helpful" for the second one.
